# Linux poll(2) is interrupted though all signals are blocked

Tags: linux, signals, polling

When my complicated, multi-threaded program calls poll(2), the call is being interrupted -- even though all signals have been blocked. Also, the installed signal handler for *all* signals is never called. I would like some ideas on what might be causing this.

The program is too complicated to include, but here is a code snippet that illustrates the problem:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#undef   NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(const int sock)
{
    sigset_t allSigs;

    sigfillset(&allSigs);

    int status = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &allSigs, NULL); // Blocks all signals
    assert(status == 0);
    {
        sigset_t sigset;
        status = sigpending(&sigset);
        assert(status == 0);
        for (int sigNum = 1; sigNum < _NSIG; ++sigNum)
            if (sigismember(&sigset, sigNum))
                fprintf(stderr, "Signal %d is pending", sigNum); // Prints nothing
    }

    struct pollfd pfd;

    pfd.fd = sock;
    pfd.events = POLLRDNORM;
    errno = 0; // Just to make sure
    status = poll(&pfd, 1, 30000); // All-signals signal-handler never called

    if (status < 0)
        perror("poll() failure"); // Prints "poll() failure: Interrupted system call"
}
```

I know, this is impossible -- yet it's happening.

If you have any ideas on what might be causing this, I'd like to hear them.

Here's my environment:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 
$ uname -a
Linux gilda 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 14 21:49:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc -dumpversion
4.8.5
```

Comment: pthread_cancel calls usually use a signal internally (commonly designated SIGCANCEL) and sigfillset skips that signal. Still, it should target the thread to be cancel not an unrelated one. Have you tried running the program under strace to see what signal is getting delivered?

Comment: And there's another signal skipped by sigfillset that libc uses internally to synchronize uid changes across threads. Perhaps that one could be causing the EINTR.

Comment: @PSkocik, Thanks for the ideas. The function `pthread_cancel()` is never called for the thread on which `poll()` is called -- so that can't be it. I didn't know about the UID-synchronizing signal. That's a possibility because the program does call `seteuid()` on another thread. I'll investigate.

Comment: I think that'll be it. Even if you did use pthread_cancel, it should only target the thread to be cancelled. In seteuid synchronization on the other hand, each and every thread must be signaled and that could certainly cause an EINTR. And while your libc will no doubt handle the signal in a handler installed with SA_RESTART, `poll` is one of the functions that get never restarted automatically (see the https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal manpage). Is it a problem to simply do `do { s=poll(/*...*/); }while(0>s &&EINTR==errno);`?

Comment: @PSkocik, Seems like non-standard behavior by `poll()`. (I try to write conforming code. Oh well...) I've adopted your suggestion with some modifications necessary because a mutex-guarded variable is set and the thread deliberately signaled when it should terminate (I find interruptions easier to handle than thread cancellations). Thanks again for the information.

Comment: @PSkocik's suggestion that it could be a UID-synchronization signal seems to be the case. Modifying the code to ignore interrupts unless the mutex-guarded variable is set did the trick.